# How to call async/await inside loop?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Please someone help me! I've tried many anwsers i found on stackoverflow, but none of they worked for me.
I'm trying to call dynamic function inside a forEach, which inside that function also has a async/await which is already working (the one returning the collection). Here is my code.

```
export default function validatorJS(data: any, validations: any) {
    let error: any = {};
    const message = {
        unique: `The value [{var}] already exists.`,
    };
    let methods: any = {
        unique: async (_field: any, _validations: any) => {
            // This is returning a collection of a Model. 
            const res = await _validations.unique.find({ [_field]: data[_field] });
            if (res.length > 0) {
                error = {
                    ...error,
                    [_field]: [...(error[_field] || []), message.unique.replace("{var}", data[_field])],
                };
            }
        },
    };

    function validate() {
        Object.keys(validations).forEach((field: any) => {
            Object.keys(validations[field]).forEach(async (method: any) => {
                if (method in methods) await methods[method](field, validations[field]);
            });
        });

        // Getting here before the methods.unique finishs
        return Object.keys(error).length > 0 ? error : false;
    }

    return validate();
}
```

Comment: Use plain `for (const field in validations) for (const method in validations[field]) …` instead of `Object.keys(…).forEach(…)`.

Comment: OMG! that works!!!, i read the reason why this works. Thank you!!!!!